# Dynamic JPA Entities in EJB Container

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, ejb

Within a GF EJB container, I am trying to dynamically discover my JPA entity classes using ServiceLoader and add them to the the JPA configuration prior to the container creating the EntityManagerFactory.  The problem I am having is finding a way to "intercept" the PersistenceProvider configuration for a specific persistence unit prior to the EMF creation.

I attempted to use Hibernate by extending the HibernatePersistence persistence provider, but have had a couple problems (see [Using Hibernate Ejb3Configuration with Container Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229745/using-hibernate-ejb3configuration-with-container-management)).  I am open to any suggestions.  My requirements are that it must run on the EJB container and utilize JPA for persistence.  I would prefer to stay with GF and stay as vendor neutral to all technologies as possible (but would appreciate any suggestions).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps here, but consider to use an OSGi approach instead of plain ServiceLoader.

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/06/14/developing-hybrid-osgi-java-ee-applications-glassfish
(I haven't studied this article fully yet, so I'm not sure if it's of any use here.)

Comment: thanks for the response.  I did indeed investigate OSGi, but I don't have a need for the service layer, versioning, lifecycle functionality, etc.  I want my EJB container (which happens to use OSGi) to do provide these services for me.  Further, the only way I can see getting JPA in OSGi to do what I want it to is to forgo the container managed entity manager and inject my own, having to deal with my own JTA and connection management -- not a deal breaker, but I want those developing plugins etc to use straight EJB technologies.  Thanks!

Comment: Accepting because this would indeed work, even if it wasn't exactly what i was going for =)